# Checking a websites text with Lua?

Tags: lua

How would I check if this has text that says "true", and if it does, it runs a piece of code?
http://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?assetId=26943368&userId=13416513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [luasocket.http.request](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) to get text from URL you need, then compare it with "true".

```
local http = require "socket.http"

local text = http.request(url)
if text == "true" then
  -- it's true!
end
```